# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 502 error with Nuxt JS

Tags: nuxt.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently trying to deploy a VUE Nuxt.JS app on AWS Elastic beanstalk. I have the same app running on Amplify seamlessly. I'm trying to run it on EBS to enable SSR functionalities on it. I keep getting 502 error

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.210.8.79, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
```

I have other micro-services running on EBS also built with node js.
Please any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect from localhost:8080?

Comment: I believe that's how EBS is configured using nginx

Comment: Then you should have added it that to the question. And the networking configuration. It's pretty hard to pinpoint the problem without information.